# How to connect Container App to custom VNet using Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to follow the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/vnet-custom?tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=azure-portal

The above step-by-step page says that to connect with a manually created Virtual Network I need to got to Networking tab in the form of creating Container App.
However there's no such tab there. Is it out-of-date documentation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the networking option, you have to select Environment type as `Consumption only` like below:

In your container apps -> create a new container Apps environment

[image]

Once you select **consumption only** you can see the networking option like below:

[image]

Choose your existing VNet and create a new infrastructure subnet with an external virtual IP and Review the settings and proceed to create.

[image]

Created container app successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks! Thanks to that I am able to create a Container App with custom TCP port set for ingress.
Do you know how to open the port (probably through NAT) so it can be accessed externally (outside the Azure services)? I have created a Container App with TCP port set to be accessible externally. However the Virtual Network is not connected to anything. I also created NAT Gateway but struggle to connect that Virtual Network and open it to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Hello @VIPPER did you able manage exposing TCP port from out side. I am also looking for same, unfortunately no luck yet...thanks

Comment: Well, I wanted to setup my own simple SMTP server written in Python with aiosmtpd module. The only task for it is to receive and parse email.
Unfortunately I couldn't do it in Azure, this is too complicated environment. I switched to another solution and right now am testing cloudmailing.com. It's easier for me to add new node in my API instead of wasting time on Azure and its lack of documentation/tutorials on "how to do things".