# Expose TCP port to external in a Container Capp

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-container-apps, virtual-network

Thanks to the community help ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769399/how-to-connect-container-app-to-custom-vnet-using-azure-portal/77772255#77772255)) I managed to setup a Container App connected to a Virtual Network and configure to open TCP port 25 to be externally accessible.

However I cannot connect to that port from telnet.
In Microsoft's documentation, I saw there is a need to create a NAT Gateway.

I created NAT but struggle to connect to the Container App I created. I also read that there is something names Application Gateway for Containers.
What should I do to get port 25 accessible publicly?

[image]

Comment: Hi Viper, port 25 is blocked by default,  Azure, has this restrictions on its use due to potential abuse for spam.

Comment: Does it mean I cannot deploy my own simple application to process email reception? Let's ignore the fact this is port 25, not encrypted, for now it's only for testing.

Comment: there is a work around i can give you a overview wait let me put it in answer section for you.

Comment: should be NSG at the subnet level, can you check NSG rules on your vnet/subnet ?

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned the outbound to port 25 is only available for EA subscription, if you need to use it, you need to change your subscription type to Enterprise Agreement, You can change SMTP relay services to resolve

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity

the second part of the question-

I think you need to Configure your Container App to listen on a different port (e.g., 1234).
In the Azure portal, navigate to your Container App.
Under "Settings," click "Networking."
Add a new port binding, specifying the private (container) port and the public port (e.g., 1234).
Save the configuration.
Access your app using the public IP/domain and the mapped port (e.g., http://yourapp.azurewebsites.net:1234).

I suggest you to reach the azure documentation page and search foe this ill give you a link there you may find the step by step guides,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Azure%20Networking%20documentation.

Comment: Okay, understood. What about following scenario. The Container App listens to 25 but the port exposed publicly is different then. I believe I can map e.g. 1234 to 25 port. How can I do it when the Container App uses custom Virtual Network? I'm completely new to Azure and struggle to figure out how to achieve public access to my app.

Comment: so you want Container App on a different public port right? like eg - (e.g., 1234)

Comment: Yep, let's discuss that scenario instead. How can I make it public and properly router through a Virtual Network, NAT Gateway, etc. Is there any tutorial to do this?

Comment: sure i got your back let me give you an overview again in the answer.

Comment: In relation to my original question, in general I want to only receive emails by my Container App, not send them.

Comment: Try this and if nothing works open a support req in azure portal, that will surely help you get a clear idea.